# Linux mount point in proc virtual filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, raspberry-pi, proc

I was asked to move this question here from stackoverflow.

I did fork guitmz's memrun repo (for asm and go).
I did provide memrun and memfd_create for C in my fork:
https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun?organization=Hermann-SW&organization=Hermann-SW#fork-mission-statement

[memfd_create.c](https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun/blob/master/C/memfd_create.c) creates a memory file (/memfd:...) and returns process pid and memory filedescriptor:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ gcc memfd_create.c -o memfd_create
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ ./memfd_create
1880 3
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ ls -l /proc/1880/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Oct  6 20:54 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Oct  6 20:54 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Oct  6 20:54 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 pi pi 64 Oct  6 20:54 3 -> '/memfd:rab.oof (deleted)'
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

Creating 10MB filesystem in memory file works:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/proc/1880/fd/3 bs=1024 count=10240 2> /dev/null
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ mkfs.ext2 /proc/1880/fd/3 > /dev/null
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

And mounting that filesystem under /proc(!) works, on 32bit Raspberry Pi OS (debian) as well as on 64bit Intel Ubuntu:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ ls -l /proc/1880/fd
total 12
drwx------ 2 root root 12288 Oct  6 20:56 lost+found
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

The same mount under /proc does not work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux:

```
$ ./memfd_create
26611 3
$ ls -l /proc/26611/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 stammw stammw 64 Oct  6 21:00 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 stammw stammw 64 Oct  6 21:00 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 stammw stammw 64 Oct  6 21:00 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 stammw stammw 64 Oct  6 21:00 3 -> '/memfd:rab.oof (deleted)'
$ 
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/proc/26611/fd/3 bs=1024 count=10240 2> /dev/null
$ mkfs.ext2 /proc/26611/fd/3 > /dev/null
mke2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
$ 
$ sudo mount /proc/26611/fd/3 /proc/26611/fd
[sudo] password for stammw: 
mount: /proc/26611/fd: cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only.
$
```

Should mounting under /proc not work at all?
In case it should, what is needed to mount successfully under /proc for RHEL?

Perhaps one word on why I do that: tcc "-run" option enhanced g++/gcc, with all gcc/g++ temporary files as well as executable in RAM, and executed from RAM:

```
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ fortune -s | bin/g++ -run demo.cpp foo 123
bar foo
Sorry.  I forget what I was going to say.
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ 
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $ cat demo.cpp 
/**
*/
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("bar %s\n", argc>1 ? argv[1] : "(undef)");

  for(char c; std::cin.read(&c, 1); )  { std::cout << c; }

  return 0;
}
pi@raspberrypi400:~/memrun/C $
```

A first answer from the other thread:

> Your RHEL output shows a . after the permissions, meaning there are additional SELinux permissions at play. Can you see what they are? –
> that other guy

On RHEL:

```
$ sudo ls -Z /proc/26611/fd
[sudo] password for stammw: 
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 0
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 1
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 2
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 3
$
$ ls -Z /proc/26611 | grep fd$
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 fd
$
```

Answer (score 2):

> The same mount under /proc does not work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux:
> `mount: /proc/26611/fd: cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only.`

You should look in your logs, and try what it says there ;-)

```
[root@rhel8 ~]# journalctl --no-pager -n1 | sed 's/^ *//'
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-10-07 03:05:03 BST, end at Thu 2021-10-07 03:10:49 BST. --
Oct 07 03:06:54 rhel8.od platform-python[2154]: SELinux is preventing mount from mounton access on the directory /proc/<pid>/fd.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that mount should be allowed mounton access on the fd directory by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'mount' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mount
# semodule -X 300 -i my-mount.pp
```

But I don't think that this is a good idea. Better leave that as it is and try something else than mounting it on `/proc/<pid>/fd`.

> tcc "-run" option enhanced g++/gcc, with all gcc/g++ temporary files as well as executable in RAM, and executed from RAM:

A temporary directory or a tmpfs will do fine for that, you're overcomplicating yourself.

Comment: I tried the ausearch and semodule commands, just hangs indefinitely

Comment: Not indefinitely, the `semodule` command just takes a while

Comment: That really works, thanks for all what I learned on selinux with your help -- but it takes 19 seconds to mount tmpfs under /proc/PID/fd, on each and every invocation. That is not useful for my "-run" enabled gcc/g++. I will let my script check for presence of /usr/sbin/getenforce, and if presenet test whether status reported is Enforcing. In that case I will create and use /tmp/PID as mount point for tmpfs, and delete after use.

Comment: Ooops -- it did 19 seconds on each transaction because I had the semodule command in the shell script I executed. After removing that now it works immediately. 
Thanks again for the "mount -t tmpfs" idea, I completely got rid of using memfd_create system call by that mount !

Comment: Thanks again, created new "-run" enabled gcc/g++ with grun tool making use of "mount -t tmpfs ...". I documented all this in new section "mount_tmpfs technique works without memfd_create system call" of my repo: https://github.com/Hermann-SW/memrun/tree/master/C#mount_tmpfs-technique-works-without-memfd_create-system-call

Answer (score 1):

> Should mounting under `/proc` not work at all?

No, the directories under `/proc` are no different from others in this respect, and provided that there are no other restrictions (see the other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672195/325065)), you can mount anything there.

A particularity of `/proc/<pid>/*` paths is that any mounts on such directories will be **lazily  unmounted [1] automatically** when `<pid>` terminates.

You can use that feature to create a temporary directory which will be automatically removed with all its content when your process terminates ---no matter how it terminates--- by mounting a tmpfs on some subdirectory of `/proc/self`.

Example script:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /proc/$$/attr
cd /proc/$$/attr
bash
```

This will leave you in a shell with its current directory in `/proc/$$/attr`, where you could create other files and directories which will all be gone as soon as you exit the shell.

But **a better alternative** is to create a private mount namespace, which will give you a lot more options on where to place the mount:

```
$ export T=$(mktemp -d)
$ unshare -Urm 
root# mount -t tmpfs t $T
root# echo > $T/somefile
root# ls $T
somefile
root# exit
$ ls $T
<nothing left>
```

Note: on some Debian-like systems, you have to enable `sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` (as root) to be able to run that as a regular user; or, instead of that, a [`cap_sys_admin+eip`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) binary wrapper could [unshare](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html) the mount namespace, set its mount propagation to private, perform the tmpfs mount (without creating an extra user namespace) and then execute another program or script.

---

[1] lazily unmounted directories are kept "floating" until all references to files and directories from them are closed. This creates a curious situation, where you have an isolated (yet fully functional) filesystem which does not appear in `/proc/mounts`, and where the `getcwd(2)` system call returns a bogus path starting with `(unreachable)/` (that had to be patched in glibc's wrapper to match the definition from POSIX, which requires `getcwd()` to either fail or return an absolute path):

```
# sleep 2 & mount -t tmpfs t /proc/$!/attr; cd /proc/$!/attr
[1] 6585
/proc/6585/attr# 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 2  (wd: ~)
/proc/6585/attr# /bin/pwd
/bin/pwd: couldn't find directory entry in '..' with matching i-node
/proc/6585/attr# strace /bin/pwd 2>&1 | grep cwd
getcwd("(unreachable)/", 4096)          = 15
/proc/6585/attr# mkdir sub        # you can still use the dir normally
```

Notice that you can also *lazily* unmount a filesystem explicitly with `umount(MNT_DETACH)`/`umount -l`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But the first script does not work for RHEL as well. I had to execute your script with sudo because of the mount. I cannot put formatted stuff into comment, see screenshot of executing script, failure to mount tmpfs as well as related jounalctl lines here: [https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/images/tmpfs_proc.png](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/images/tmpfs_proc.png)

Comment: Regarding use of mktemp, it creates temp file under /tmp, which is not even a tmpfs under Raspberry Pi OS. Target is to provide "-run" enabled gcc/g++ that just work, without users having to modify /etc/fstab.

Comment: **1.** The first script works on rhel8 if you fix the selinux restrictions as described in the other answer **2.** Of course you should be root to be able to mount anything (or gain at least the [`CAP_SYS_ADMIN`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) by running a "setcap" binary),  **3.** The second script does not require root **4.** The `mktemp` is just used to create an empty directory to use as a mount point, you can use `/var/empty` or any other dir instead. **5.** I haven't modified `/etc/fstab` (or even assumed that a `/etc/fstab` existed) anywhere ;-)